# Apache Flink: How to use DISTINCT in a TUMBLE time window?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

I have a stream like this: `<_time(timestamp), uri(string), userId(int)>`.
The `_time` attribute is rowtime and I register it as a table:

```
tableEnv.registerDataStream("userVisitPage", stream, "_time.rowtime, uri,userId");
```

Then I query the table:

```
final String sql =
       "SELECT tumble_start(_time, interval '10' second) as timestart, " +
       "  count(distinct userId) as uv, " +
       "  uri as uri, " +
       "  count(1) as pv " +
       "FROM userVisitPage " +
       "GROUP BY tumble(_time, interval '10' second), uri";

final Table table = tableEnv.sqlQuery(sql);
```

However, the query throws an exception:

```
org.apache.flink.table.codegen.CodeGenException: Unsupported call: TUMBLE 
If you think this function should be supported, you can create an issue and start a discussion for it.
    at org.apache.flink.table.codegen.CodeGenerator$$anonfun$visitCall$3.apply(CodeGenerator.scala:1006)
    at org.apache.flink.table.codegen.CodeGenerator$$anonfun$visitCall$3.apply(CodeGenerator.scala:1006)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.flink.table.codegen.CodeGenerator.visitCall(CodeGenerator.scala:1006)
    at org.apache.flink.table.codegen.CodeGenerator.visitCall(CodeGenerator.scala:67)
    at org.apache.calcite.rex.RexCall.accept(RexCall.java:107)
    at org.apache.flink.table.codegen.CodeGenerator.generateExpression(CodeGenerator.scala:234)
    at org.apache.flink.table.codegen.CodeGenerator$$anonfun$7.apply(CodeGenerator.scala:321)
    at org.apache.flink.table.codegen.CodeGenerator$$anonfun$7.apply(CodeGenerator.scala:321)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
    at org.apache.flink.table.codegen.CodeGenerator.generateResultExpression(CodeGenerator.scala:321)
    at org.apache.flink.table.plan.nodes.CommonCalc$class.generateFunction(CommonCalc.scala:44)
    at org.apache.flink.table.plan.nodes.datastream.DataStreamCalc.generateFunction(DataStreamCalc.scala:43)
    at org.apache.flink.table.plan.nodes.datastream.DataStreamCalc.translateToPlan(DataStreamCalc.scala:116)
    at org.apache.flink.table.plan.nodes.datastream.DataStreamGroupAggregate.translateToPlan(DataStreamGroupAggregate.scala:113)
    at org.apache.flink.table.plan.nodes.datastream.DataStreamGroupAggregate.translateToPlan(DataStreamGroupAggregate.scala:113)
    at org.apache.flink.table.plan.nodes.datastream.DataStreamCalc.translateToPlan(DataStreamCalc.scala:97)
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.StreamTableEnvironment.translateToCRow(StreamTableEnvironment.scala:837)
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.StreamTableEnvironment.translate(StreamTableEnvironment.scala:764)
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.StreamTableEnvironment.translate(StreamTableEnvironment.scala:734)
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.java.StreamTableEnvironment.toRetractStream(StreamTableEnvironment.scala:414)
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.java.StreamTableEnvironment.toRetractStream(StreamTableEnvironment.scala:357)
```

How can I implement this query?

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace of the exception?

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** Flink 1.6.0 is available and supports DISTINCT aggregates on streaming tables.

Flink (version 1.4.x) does not support SQL queries with `DISTINCT` aggregations on streaming tables yet. Support is targeted for Flink 1.6 which won't be released before mid 2018.

You can however implement a [user-defined aggregation function](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/table/udfs.html#aggregation-functions) to compute distinct counts and use that function in your queries after registering them. The query syntax will be different of course.

Comment: As it use the window , so how to reset the Accumulator at the end of window time ? The resetAccumulator would be called automatically by flink at the end of window ? for example we need to  reset the Accumulator before the next  new window tumble.

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't understand your question. I'd recommend to post to the Flink mailing list which is better suited to discuss implementation details. Also, Flink 1.6.0 has been released with support for `DISTINCT` aggregations.